# How to properly do nested routing in Obelisk?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, reflex

I have been [searching for examples](https://github.com/search?q=%22Obelisk.Route%22+language%3Ahaskell+pushed%3A%3E2019-04-01&type=Code), however most examples do a `RouteSomething -> PathSegment "firstpath" $ unitEncoder mempty` and not a single nested route.

There are some examples that use `Cat.id` to pass the whole URI as a Text such [Characher-Sheet](https://github.com/blargg/Character-Sheet):

```hs
backendRouteEncoder = mkFullRouteEncoder
  (FullRoute_Backend BackendRoute_Missing :/ ())
  (\case
    BackendRoute_API -> PathSegment "api" $ Cat.id
    BackendRoute_Missing -> PathSegment "missing" $ unitEncoder mempty
  )
```

and then on the backend parse the whole route:

```hs
server sql (BackendRoute_API :=> Identity _) = dir "api" $
    route [ ("spelllist/", runReaderT spellListHandler sql)
          , ("featlist/", runReaderT featListHandler sql)
          ]
```

however, this feels odd since I would have thought all routing would have been defined in `Common.Route` with `Obelisk.Route` as per the skeleton of `ob init` and other examples defining routes exclusively there. I would appreciate the safety of exhaustiveness check of the LambdaCase over the datatype codifying routes and not having to add BackendRoute_Missing equivalent on all possible backend/frontend subroutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data FrontendRoute :: * -> * where
  FrontendRoute_Sub :: FrontendRoute (R SubRoute)
data SubRoute :: * -> * where
  SubRoute_Foo :: SubRoute ()
```

Then replace `unitEncoder` with `pathComponentEncoder $ \case ...`

See [obelisk-oauth](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/obelisk-oauth#commonroute--obeliskoauthauthorization) for another example.